# how to get ng-model value inside the ng-repeat angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope

```
<div ng-controller="myctr">
<div ng-repeat="model in models">
    Value: {{model.name}}
    <input ng-model="model.name">                         
</div>
     <button type="submit" class="button button-balanced"  ng-click="saveAllValues()"> </button>
 </div>



$http.put('http://192.168.1.55:8000/api/ClickEmployeeNumgoal/' +$sessionStorage.ClickEmployeeNum , $sessionStorage)
   .success(function (response){
   $scope.models = [] ;
    $scope.models = response;

   })
```

How to get ng-model values[] in angular controller???

```
$scope.empgoalNumber = [];

  $scope.saveAllValues = function(req,res)
  {
      $scope.empgoalNumber.push($scope.model.name);
     }
```

Error is name is undefined......how to define global array to access all ng-model inside the ng-repeat ???

Comment: You should explain what you are trying to achieve here. What object do you want to send in put call etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a global (or a scope level) variable.

```
$scope.ngmodelvalue = [];
$scope.saveAllValues = function(res, req) {
  $scope.ngmodelvalue.push($scope.model.name);
}
```

And you can get the values by using `$scope.ngmodelvalue`.

Comment: @PulithevanS That's a different issue buddy. The `model` is not a Scope variable.

Comment: ya ya buddy..model is $scope variable but using another function (get to set ng-repeat function) ....what to do buddy???

Comment: @PulithevanS Dei mama, I guess it it local to that scope. Can you please add a global scope there?

Comment: @PulithevanS Dei can you show me the full code in jsbin.com please?